# Swift - How to set cookie in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to set cookie in my HTTP request
and I thought that below code would work:

```
let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("key=value;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
```

but this code is not working.
does anyone have idea how to set it?

Comment: It is working with me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Updated answer for Swift 3**

You want to look at [HTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage).

```
// First
let jar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
let cookieHeaderField = ["Set-Cookie": "key=value"] // Or ["Set-Cookie": "key=value, key2=value2"] for multiple cookies
let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: cookieHeaderField, for: url)
jar.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: url)

// Then
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
```

---

**Original answer for swift 2**

You want to look at [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/).

```
// First
let jar = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
let cookieHeaderField = ["Set-Cookie": "key=value"] // Or ["Set-Cookie": "key=value, key2=value2"] for multiple cookies
let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(cookieHeaderField, forURL: url)
jar.setCookies(cookies, forURL: url, mainDocumentURL: url)

// Then
let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
```

Comment: after quite app and reopen cookies gone.

Comment: @Bunthoeun using `"key=value"` creates a session cookie. If you want a cookie that lasts longer than the session, you need to set max age. `"key=value;path=/;max-age=30758400"` sets a cookie that lasts 1 year. See [Set-Cookie Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

```
if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
    .domain: ".my.domain.name.com",
    .path: "/",
    .name: "myCookieNameKey",
    .value: "K324klj23KLJKH223423CookieValueDSFLJ234",
    .secure: "FALSE",
    .discard: "TRUE"
]) {
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
    print("Cookie inserted: \(cookie)")
}
```

Comment: How to add multiple cookies?

Answer (score 6):

This may be useful for some one(Swift 5).
Avoid using `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift. Instead follow the below snippet:

```
func request(with url: URL) -> URLRequest {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: url) else {
        return request
    }

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies)
    return request
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it works in Swift 3.x after you set cookie using HTTPCookieStorage

```
let cookies=HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: URL(string: cookieURL)!)
let headers=HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies!)
let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL!)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields=headers
```